# Writing to a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

When this writes to a CSV file, its writing each letter into its own cell. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

I'm trying to write 'name' to its own cells.

Thanks!

```
import json
import csv
from unidecode import unidecode

def main():
  csv_writer = open_csv() #returns the functionality to write to a csv
  str_data = []
  with open('location') as f:
    for line in f:
      str_data.append(json.loads(line))
  data = str_data[0]
  for item in data['contacts']:
    linkedin_name = unidecode(name(item))
    write_to_csv(csv_writer, linkedin_name)


def name(item):
 name = item['name']
 return name


def open_csv():
  final_csv = open('test.csv', 'wb')
  csv.writer = csv.writer(final_csv)
  return csv.writer

def write_to_csv(csv_writer, linkedin_name):
  csv_writer.writerow(linkedin_name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: The line that goes `csv.writer = csv.writer(final_csv)` is fit for Halloween I guess ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
csv_writer.writerow(linkedin_name)
```

Is expecting a list. Try changing it to:

```
csv_writer.writerow([linkedin_name])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
csv_writer.writerow([linkedin_name])
```

You can pass any iterable to `writerow`, and it will print one cell per element. A string is iterable, and the elements are individual characters, so that's why your current code doesn't work. A list is the most convenient way to write something iterable with one specified element. You could just as well pass a tuple, but the syntax for a one-element tuple is a little unpleasant: `csv_writer.writerow((linkedin_name,))`